# MS Access SQL query results

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables:

```
rapprovals_tbl

rId rAssignment rState  rApprover   rapprovaldt rType   rNotes
    12345678                    
1   12345679    Paid    12345678    31/05/2015 18:23    Flex    
5   12345679    Approved    12345678    14/05/2015 18:23    Normal  
6   12345679    Pending         Normal  

timerecord_tbl

RowID   Assignment1 wMonth  StartTime   EndTime     
1   12345679    Mar-15  17/03/2015 11:29    18/03/2015 16:12    Flex    
5   12345679    Mar-15  17/03/2015 11:00    17/03/2015 12:00    Normal  
6   12345679    Mar-15  17/03/2015 11:50    18/03/2015 16:11    Normal
```

I have form with two combo boxes, which are linked and worked on this source;
Box 1 -

```
Select [staffid] FROM [control_tbl] WHERE [supervisorid]  = '12345678'
```

Box 2

```
SELECT timerecord_tbl.[RowID]
FROM timerecord_tbl
INNER JOIN rapprovals_tbl ON timerecord_tbl.RowID = rapprovals_tbl.rId
WHERE (((timerecord_tbl.[Assignment1])='" & Box 1 & "'
    AND (rapprovals_tbl.[rState] is null ) Or (rapprovals_tbl.[rState] = 'Pending' )));
```

I want to get only those RowID  which are related to Box 1 employee record in Box 2.

How do I go about this, currently its listing all row ids.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you have `and` and `or` mixed without using `()` to enforce execution order. you probably want `AND ((...) OR (...))`. note the extra `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your SQL for Box 2, like this:

```
SELECT timerecord_tbl.[RowID]
FROM timerecord_tbl
INNER JOIN rapprovals_tbl ON timerecord_tbl.RowID = rapprovals_tbl.rId
WHERE (timerecord_tbl.[Assignment1]='" & Box 1 & "')
   AND ((rapprovals_tbl.[rState] is null ) Or (rapprovals_tbl.[rState] = 'Pending' )));
```

I think @MarcB was saying the same thing.  Your "OR" statement was being applied to the entire WHERE clause instead of just the other rState filter.  Changing the parentheses will separate it properly and fix it.